# Use image icons in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am migrating from Twitter Bootstrap v2 to v3.  In v2 I had a dozen or so custom icons defined in css:

```
.icon-pc {
    background-image: url("pc.png");
    background-position: center center;
}
```

I know that in Twitter Bootstrap v3 they now use Glyphicons, but this isn't a realistic approach for me to use, as my icons are multi-colored PNG files and wouldn't work well as a font...

Is there an easy way to get these work in v3 like the old v2 icons did?

Comment: If you dig into the source of sprites.less in bootstrap, you'll see that the icon code of bootstrap is pretty small. It wouldn't be hard to create your own icon class set.

Comment: @MikeRobinson - Thanks, worked like a charm.

Comment: If multiple colours for the same icon are holding you back from using the glyphicons, do you realize you can add a second class to define the colour? eg: <i class="icon-name red"></i> then define .red in your style sheet.

Comment: @MattLambert - By multiple colors I don't mean red glpyhs, and green glpyhs, I mean a full color PNG icon which in my case probably contains 40 or 50 colors of pixels.

Comment: @Peter oh ok I see what you mean, yep png is the best route then

Answer (score 1):

Copied this block from the sprites.less generated css, worked like a charm:

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  *margin-right: .3em;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-position: 14px 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Now my good old `<i class="icon-custom"></i>` works fine.